# PSR-4 not autoloading class files?

Tags: php

Index: `<?php require '../application/bootstrap.php'; ?>`

Bootstrap:

```
<?php

define("START", microtime(true));
define("ROOT", realpath(__DIR__.'/../'));

include '../vendor/autoload.php';

include ROOT . '/application/Library/Application.php';

App\Application::getClass('test')->test();
```

Composer.JSON:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "application/"
    }
}
```

The problem is with this line:

```
include ROOT . '/application/Library/Application.php';
```

I shouldn't have to include it, PSR-4 should do it for me. Here is my Application class.

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Application
{
    public static function getClass($library){} // removed body for minimal example
}

?>
```

Here is my file structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8ONk.png, Vendor folder is hidden in my IDE as I configured it like that in my VSCode settings, although it is there.

Answer (score 0):

Your PSR-4 namespace says ROOT of `App` namespace is at folder `application/`, but your file is at path `/application/Library/Application.php`. With this config you either move `Application.php` to `/application/Application.php` or you set namespace of your application class to `App\Library`;

That should solve your problem.